# How to look for a webelement with out an exception being thrown?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to verify to see some webelement is present or not on my result page, using id attribute. It is throwing an exception when such webelement is not present and it is NOT acceptable. In the Selenium API JavaDoc, it was recommended that 'findElement' should not be used to look for non-present elements, use 'findElements(By)' instead and assert zero length response. But this is also throwing an exception, I don't know why !! Any alternate suggestions?

```
try{
//  THE PRESENT CODE TO BE MODIFIED. NOT TO THROW exception.***********
//              if(driver1.findElement(By.id(orderResultsCheckbox_0)) != null)
//                  return true;
//              *****************************

       //Instead I wrote as below...

                if(  
                    (driver1.findElements(By.id(orderResultsCheckbox_0) != null)) && (driver1.findElements(By.id(orderResultsCheckbox_0)).length() > 0)
                  )
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                println "Exception Thrown ==========>";
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: PraNuta could you please post a screenshot of the error you are getting?

Comment: My bad!
Yes, the length() method call is not available on the java.util.LIst class.
I should be using size().
This time it worked.

Comment: How to mark as answered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **findElements** method returns a list of webelements and you can check whether the list contains any webelements using the **size()** method. Hence, replace your existing code with following and let me know whether it resolves your issue:

```
if(driver1.findElements(By.id(orderResultsCheckbox_0)).size() != 0)
         return true;
else
         return false;
```

Comment: Yes. It is my bad !
It is working now.
Since, I am using this Java code inside a groovy file, the codeassist is NOT working well. It just highlights the wrong method call and puts an underline beneath it. I was spoiled by Java codeassist functionality which quite not available in groovy editors in Eclipse.

Comment: Great. If I have answered your question, then could you mark it as accepted? Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for information on how to accept an answer. Thanks.